# How to clear all values in a container control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-selectors

how can i clear all inputs with `type=text` and `type=select`(set selected index to 0)?

I thought this must be  easy with jQuery, i don't want to postback to the server for this.

This is what i have:

```
function clearValues(containerControlID) {
    $('#' + containerControlID + ' :input').each(function (index) {
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```

But i find all inputs(images,checkboxes etc). I only want to clear textareas, text-inputs and selects.

So how can i find these `inputs` with jQuery and clear their values or set the selected index of `selects` to 0?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There shouldn't be multiple elements with the same ID. IDs are meant to be unique on one page. With the ID's given you don't really need more selectors. Otherwise use the `filter` method or try the already posted anwer. -- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: @Smamatti: I'm not sure if i understand your argument. I don't have multiple elements with the same id. But i only have the ID of the container control(div or table). I don't want to use the control's ID's since they're are not predictable, e.g. `ctl00_MainContent_TabContainer1_TabDeliveryControl_SVCSDeliveryControl_RMAInfo1_NotificationConfig1_FV_Trigger_TxtActiveUntil`.

Comment: @Smamatti: I have the container id because it's [ClientIdMode](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40) is `static`, as the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function clearValues(containerControlID) {
    $('#' + containerControlID + ' :input:text').val(''); //To set all text to empty
    $('#' + containerControlID + ' textarea').val('');  
    $('#' + containerControlID + ' select').each(function () {
        this.selectedIndex = 0; //To set all select elements to first option
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. But the selector for the textarea doesn't work as expected. It also selects textareas outside of the container. I've edited your answer to add the `containerControlID`.

Comment: Edited your answer again to add my final solution. Thank you again. By the way, why do i need the `:` in the `input` selector and not in the `textarea` selector?

Comment: Becuase textarea is not a input type element it has its own tag `textarea` so jQuery finds it by tag name where as `text` element is input type element and `:` indicates jQuery to select element by type.